# Getting E210007 cannot negotiate authentication mechanism when using svn:// protocol on CentOS 6.3

Tags: svn, centos, kerberos

My project requires to programatically checkout code from svn and we use the svn protocol as we use kerberos authentication mechanism to an Active Directory. However when I run the tests I get errors. So I tried checking it out at command line just to confirm if I get the same errors, and I did get the same error. What am I missing? I made sure I installed `mod_dav_svn`, `subversion & cyrus-sasl-md5`, `cyrus-sasl-gssapi` packages, but still getting this error:

```
svn: E210007: Unable to connect to a repository at URL: ...  
svn: E210007: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism
```

Any ideas? Any packages/conf I am missing?

Comment: The issue was the kerberos key was set as a root user, which needed password at execution time. Changed it to a normal user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the kerberos key was set as a root user, which needed password at execution time. Changed it to a normal user!